# blkid can't find lvm's uuid

Tags: partitioning, mount, lvm

I created two LVM partitions, and can mount/use them. But when I try to mount it with UUID I get a message that says it can't find the UUID.

```
sudo lvdisplay
--- Logical volume ---
LV Path                /dev/vg00/VolProject
LV Name                VolProject
VG Name                vg00
LV UUID                HUhRED-ZUwG-cutq-fniL-1OOE-cZrd-ofoDZ3
LV Write Access        read/write
LV Creation host, time ubuntu, 2017-04-04 18:41:55 -0700
LV Status              available
# open                 1
LV Size                17.00 GiB
Current LE             4351
Segments               3
Allocation             inherit
Read ahead sectors     auto
- currently set to     256
Block device           252:0

--- Logical volume ---
LV Path                /dev/vg00/volBackup
LV Name                volBackup
VG Name                vg00
LV UUID                KZ6Y65-L9Qo-ShIz-pQ88-nIyD-P1n5-RGWcrw
LV Write Access        read/write
LV Creation host, time ubuntu, 2017-04-04 18:42:42 -0700
LV Status              available
# open                 0
LV Size                6.99 GiB
Current LE             1790
Segments               2
Allocation             inherit
Read ahead sectors     auto
- currently set to     256
Block device           252:1

ubuntu:/dev/vg00$ cat /etc/fstab
UUID=56b92ca1-312c-45e6-8f57-8c80762f96b9 / ext4 errors=remount-ro 0       1
UUID=07d0cb84-79a6-47bd-a155-cbfd045cf6ca none swap sw             0       0
/dev/fd0        /media/floppy0  auto    rw,user,noauto,exec,utf8   0       0
#/dev/vg00/VolProject /home/davy/mnt auto defaults 0 0
UUID=HUhRED-ZUwG-cutq-fniL-1OOE-cZrd-ofoDZ3 /home/davy/mnt auto defaults 0 0
ubuntu:/dev/vg00$ blkid /dev/vg00/VolProject
ubuntu:/dev/vg00$ blkid /dev/vg00/volBackup
```

and when I do the mount -a:

```
ubuntu:/dev/vg00$ sudo mount -a
mount: can't find UUID=HUhRED-ZUwG-cutq-fniL-1OOE-cZrd-ofoDZ3
```

why is this happening? If I used the mount via /dev/vg00/VolProject it works, but if I use it's UUID it says that it can't find it. VG is created per instructions here: http://www.tecmint.com/manage-and-create-lvm-parition-using-vgcreate-lvcreate-and-lvextend/

Comment: You don't mount the LV; you mount the *filesystem created on* the LV, which has its own UUID:  if `blkid` isn't seeing it make sure you clear the cache `sudo blkid -c /dev/null`.

Comment: Run this `sudo blkid /dev/vg00/VolProject` it should give you a UUID to mount

Comment: neither of the two suggestions work for me.   i found the UUID by lookin in fdisk -l for the name of the device and then get the uid with blkid once i had the name as spelled by OS (which is not the one LVM shows)

Answer (score 4):

Actually, you were confused between `lvm UUID` and `block UUID`.

The below command will display your `lvm UUID`, it point to specific item under `lvm`.

```bsh
$ lvdisplay Logical-Volume
```

The below command will display your `blcok UUID`, it point to specific block device in your system.

```bsh
$ blkid /dev/YOUR-Virtual-Group/YOUR-Logical-Volume
```

You should always use `block UUID` or `device file` instead of `lvm UUID` to modify the `/etc/fstab` record.

Comment: What if there isn't a "block UUID" (like dm-integrity devices right now)?